# Ansvered / How to use content from database in PHP functions?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP function which converts #Hashtag into a link...

```
function convertHashtags($str) {
 $regex = "/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/";
 $str = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="hashtag.php?tag=$1">$0</a>', $str);
 return($str);
}
```

It work properly when I use it with a common string

```
$string = "Hello #World";
$string = convertHashtags($string);
```

(in this case an output would be: Hello [#World](https://stackoverflow.com/#)

But when I'm trying to insert something from my database to that string it displays, but without that function's effect…

```
$string = $row["content"];
$string = convertHashtags($string);
```

(an output: Hello #World)

I am new to the PHP and MySQL stuff… Certainly, there are many things I don't know yet :D

What's wrong with this function?

Thanks!

Comment: What does `var_dump($row["content"])` return?

Comment: string(12) "Hello #World"

Comment: That works as expected. Please add more code, something else must be happening.

Comment: Can you include the output of: `echo base64_encode($row['content']);`

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertHashtags($str){
      list($str1, $str2) = explode("#", $str) ;
      $str2 = '<a href="http://www.hashtag.php?tag='.$str2.'">#'.$str2.'</a>';
      $str = $str1." ".$str2 ;
      return($str);
}
```

Can you use the above function and test with database entry?

Answer (score -1):

Oh well, I just add new element to a database and it works!

I was testing it on old elements, they was inserted before I wrote the function.

I should try it before writing a this, my bad… thanks for help anyway!

Comment: This reads like you are transforming your hash tags into links and storing in the database.  Rather than transforming upon/after retrieval.

Answer (score -4):

```
$string = $row["content"];
$string = (string)$string;
$string = convertHashtags($string);
```

Use the above code and it will work.

Comment: Did you use the above code ? Please use and check the result.

Comment: Data coming from SQL will always be a string. There is no reason or need to cast it.

Comment: I didn't use the above code but since the `var_dump` shows `string` this would have the same affect. It is not my question, but I am sure this will not resolve the issue.

Comment: `$string = (string) $string;` reminded me of this joke: http://hvac-talk.com/vbb/showthread.php?1135141-The-three-strings-Clean-joke